# Can you get the salt knowing plaintext and hash?

Tags: database, security, hash, passwords, salt

Can you get the SALT from a password, knowing the hash and plaintext?

**For Example:**

**Hash**: fc203f1c0a0c0636527086f071d83b1e

**Plaintext**: admin

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/225787/compute-salt-with-known-plaintext-and-hash

Comment: The fields aren't visibly separated, so this does not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you know or can guess the method used to generate the hash. Simply bruteforce the salt  value instead of the password value. You may have to write a custom brute forcer. If you're lucky you can adapt a flexible one such as this: https://github.com/wireghoul/presentations/tree/master/BHAsia2014/cuda